# Draw highcharts in td of table

Tags: html, charts, highcharts, html-table

I need to write a table like below and in some rows there is a chart include line and scatter.

[image]

This is what i get when i try with table in html and highchart in a td tag. But I need to set size of chart and margin in the specific way so it'snot responsive. Does anyone have other suggestions to slove this? Many thanks

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? I see no codes in your question.

Comment: Could you please reproduce your example in the working demo? You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jrah5yvf/